# Start background processes from a background process

Tags: php, linux, process, background-process

I have a PHP script say `test.php` in linux Ubuntu, in this PHP script I use `shell_exec()` to start several background processes.

When I execute `php test.php`, the background processes are started as expected, but when I run `php test.php &`, those several background processes are not started.

Is it not a supported way to start background processes from a background process, or is there a better to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `php test.php < /dev/null &` - some Unix distributions seem to expect some input and send the process idle to background. Tested on Fedora Linux (bash) you can start `php test.php &` but it isn't executed. Check with `jobs` running background process - catch from background and execute with `fg`.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by using [proc_open](http://www.php.net/proc_open). I've written a [micro-framework](https://github.com/airbone42/Houston) as POC, which is using this technique.